How does average_precision_score metric in scikit-learn work for non-probability prediction scores
Scikit-learn has an AP metric function Here
The description of y_score (predictions) says :- Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions
So the case of simple probability scores for y_score is easy to understand like the one below.
y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
average_precision_score(y_true, y_scores)

Which gives a value of 0.83
But what is unclear is how are then, non-probability values like the following handled
y_true = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
y_scores = np.array([3.4, 12.1, 8.35, 0.8])
average_precision_score(y_true, y_scores)

Gives an AP value of 0.416. Are these values converted to some sort of probability values before computing the metric?
And then when we use negative values for scores, so y_scores = np.array([-3.4, -12.1, -8.35, -0.8]) then gives AP value of 1.0
Why does using negative values, change the AP metric in comparison to their positive counterparts.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You don't have to set thresholds on a probability scale. If your predictions are y_score = np.array([0.8, 3.4, 8.35, 12.1]), a perfectly reasonable set of thresholds is np.array([0, 1, 4, 10, 20]). You then classify those points according to which side of the threshold they fall; above is the positive class and below the negative class.
Alternatively, you can just apply a sigmoidal function to the non-probability values to compress them to the interval $[0, 1]$.
transformed_scores = 1/(1 + np.exp(-y_scores))
print(average_precision_score(y_true, transformed_scores))

Much like area under the ROC curve, average precision (equal to area under the PR curve) does not change when strictly increasing monotonic functions are applied to the values.

And why do using the negative score prediction for the same set of values, results in increase in AP metric?

@Anmol What do you mean by the negative score prediction? Do you mean that average_precision_score(y_true, -y_scores) = 1?

Yes, when doing average_precision_score(y_true, y_scores) we AP = 0.416 but when using y_scores = -y_scores, we get AP metric = 1.0

When you have your predictions as -y_score, then $-6$ (among other values) is a perfect threshold: using such a threshold results in perfect classifications. It seems that the function works as follows. Calculate over all reasonable thresholds. If a threshold gives perfect classifications, that is the lone reasonable threshold and gives an average precision of $1$.

There are other cases as well where it increase, even without AP of 1. For eg.
y_true = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
y_scores = np.array([3.4, 12.1, 8.35, 0.8, 1.7])
average_precision_score(y_true, y_scores) ==> 0.36
average_precision_score(y_true, -y_scores) ==> 0.83
Here there is no perfect threshold but we still see an increase

@Anmol You have different predictions (critically, a different ranking of predictions). Shouldn't a change in performance be expected? You don't expect the same performance from you regression model that predicts (2, 3, 4) as when it predicts (17, 2, 3), do you?

Got it, yes you are right, reversing the sign also reverses the meaning of the value, so for eg. 12.1 with positive sign mean higher confidence of being "positive class" while -12.1 means higher confidence of being "negative class"

@Anmol If this resolves your inquiry, you could consider upvoting and accepting to “close out” the question and signal to others that my response is helpful.
